# Maven: How to print the current profile on the console?

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin, maven-profiles

I'm trying to print the current profile that is active running a build of a Maven Project.

I'm using the `maven-antrun-plugin` in order to print messages on the console, in combination with a property that refers to the current profile.

I have tried the following properties:

```
${project.activeProfiles[0].id}

${project.profiles[0].id}
```

But in both cases it prints the "string" as it is written, without resolving the variable.

This is my test:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>current active profile: ${project.activeProfiles[0].id}</echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But this is the result that I obtain:

```
main:
 [echo] current active profile: ${project.activeProfiles[0].id}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do specifically, that depends on the profile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [maven-help-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin) offers what you need. It has an [active-profiles](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/active-profiles-mojo.html) goal.

You can add it to your pom or even call it from the command line (include it in your maven build call). The *How can I tell which profiles are in effect during a build?* section of the [Maven profile introduction page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) will show you how. In short:

```
mvn help:active-profiles
```

---

As this does not work for you (see comments) here is another solution:

I think the active profiles (there can be more than one!) are not propagated as [available variables](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables) - but properties are.

So set a custom property in the profile section and use that, like

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <myProfile>default</myProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>debug</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>debug</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <myProfile>debug</myProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo>current active profile: ${myProfile}</echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I need. I want to print the profile accessing it by a variable, because I want to do some operations based on the profile.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I need! Thanks!

Comment: Where is myProfile coming from?  Where is it set?

Answer (score 4):

you can add the maven-help-plugin in your pom to display always the active profile

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- display active profile in compile phase -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>show-profiles</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

source: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/maven-profiles-example